# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when fetching core data

Tags: swift, core-data, binary, fetch, binary-data

In my swift code the goal is to fetch an attribute and display it on an image view. I am having trouble fetching the attribute pic which is a binary data.

> if let imageData = Pictucre[imageNo].pic

```
    func getImage(imageNo:Int) {
       // first check the array bounds
        let info = CoredataHandler.shareInstance.fetchImage()
       
        
        print("image count is", info.count)
       if info.count > imageNo {
           
           // check if the data is available
           
           
        
           if let imageData = Pictucre[imageNo].pic
                
              
            
            {
           imagePlace.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
               
           } else {
               // no data
               print("data is empty Textss")
           }
       } else {
           // image number is greater than array bounds
           print("you are asking out of bounds")
       }
    }

}



class CoredataHandler : NSManagedObject {
    static let shareInstance = CoredataHandler()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
 
    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    func saveImage(data: Data) {
        let imageInstance = Pictucre(context: context)
        
        
        imageInstance.pic = data
            
        do {
            try context.save()
          
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    class func fetchObject() -> [Pictucre]?
    {
        let context = getContext()
        var max : [Pictucre]? = nil
        do {
            max = try context.fetch(Pictucre.fetchRequest())
            
            
            return max
            
        } catch {
            return max
        }
        
    }
  
    
    

    func fetchImage() -> [Pictucre] {
        
      
        var fetchingImage = [Pictucre]()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Max")
        
        do {
            
            fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Pictucre]
        } catch {
            print("Error while fetching the image")
        }
        
        return fetchingImage
    }
    
    
   

}
```

[pic of core data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulOnw.png)
the error states Type of expression is ambiguous without more context. It is a runtime error

I tried adding a ! to pic making it pic! and that still causes a runtime error.

Comment: What is `Pictucre[imageNo]`, do you really have an array property with the exact same name as your entity?

Comment: Pictucre is not a property it is my core data entity where imageNo is a int. I am trying to fetch a specific item from the core data attribute pic when is in the entity of Pictucre.

Comment: Then why are you using an index? This makes no sense

Comment: what would i use to get a specific item from a array if i dont use imageNo

Comment: You would need an array then but you said it wasn't an array. Or is `info` your array because then it would be `info[imageCount].pic`